# Printing a consloge.log() status

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a javascript assignment:

Write yourself a virtual cat - animals with a CLI are so much nicer than ones with fur.

Create an object that represents a cat. It should have properties for tiredness, hunger, loneliness, and happiness
Next, write methods that increase and decrease those properties. Call them something that actually represents what would increase or decrease these things, like "feed", "sleep", or "pet".
Last, write a method that prints out the cat's status in each area. (Be creative e.g. Paws is really hungry, Paws is VERY happy.)

So in my last line of code, I want to check to make sure I can print the status and see what response I get, but don't think that my last consol.log() is correct. Could anyone help me out? Also, do you think there are any errors in this code or a way I can shorten it?

```
 class Paws {
 constructor() {
 this.tiredness = 0;
 this.hunger = 0;
 this.loneliness = 0;
 this.happiness = 0;
 }

play(tirednessVal, lonelinessVal, hungerVal) {
this.tiredness += tirednessVal;
this.loneliness -= lonelinessVal;
this.hunger += hungerVal;
 }
sleep(tirednessVal, lonelinessVal) {
this.tiredness -= tirednessVal;
this.loneliness += lonelinessVal;
}

eat(hungerVal, happinessVal) {
this.hunger -= hungerVal;
this.happiness += happinessVal;
}

getAngry(happinessVal) {
  this.happiness -= happinessVal;
}

printStatus() {
 const isTired = "The cat is very tired";
 const isNotTired = "The cat is not tired";
 const isHungry = "The cat is very hungry";
 const isNotHungry = "The cat is not hungry";
 const isLonely = "The cat is very lonely";
 const isNotLonely = "The cat is not lonely";
 const isHappy = "The cat is super happy";
 const isNotHappy = "The cat is not happy";

if (this.tiredness > 10) {
  console.log(isTired);
} else {
  console.log(isNotTired);
}
if (this.hunger > 10) {
  console.log(isHungry);
} else {
  console.log(isNotHungry);
}
if (this.loneliness > 10) {
  console.log(isLonely);
} else {
  console.log(isNotLonely);
}
if (this._happiness > 10) {
  console.log(isHappy);
} else {
  console.log(isNotHappy);
 }
 }

pet() {
  if (this.happiness < 5) {
   console.log("Meow. Don't touch me!");
  } else {
    meow();
  }
}   
 meow() {
  console.log("Moew. Pet me more");
 }

 console.log(Paws.tiredness(4));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an interesting assignment. here is mine

```js
 class Cat {
   constructor(name, tiredness = 0, hunger = 10, loneliness = 10, happiness = 0) {
     this.name = name;
     this.tiredness = tiredness;
     this.hunger = hunger;
     this.loneliness = loneliness;
     this.happiness = happiness;
   }
   normalizeValue(val) {
    if (val < 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (val > 10) {
        return 10;
    }
    return val;
   }
   play(val = 1) {
     this.loneliness = this.normalizeValue(this.loneliness - val);
     this.happiness = this.normalizeValue(this.happiness + val);
   }
   feed(val = 1) {
     this.hunger = this.normalizeValue(this.hunger - val);
   }
   pet(val = 1) {
     this.loneliness = this.normalizeValue(this.loneliness - val);
   }
   sleep(val = 1) {
     this.tiredness = this.normalizeValue(this.tiredness - val);
   }
   getStatus() {
     return {
       tired: this.tiredness > 5,
       hungry: this.hunger > 5,
       lonely: this.loneliness > 5,
       happy: this.happiness > 5
     }
   }
   toString() {
     const status = this.getStatus();

     return Object.keys(status).map(k => {
       const state = status[k] ? "is" : "is not";
       return `${this.name} ${state} ${k}`;
     }).join(". ") + ".";
   }
 }

 const paws = new Cat("paws");
 paws.play(6);
 paws.feed(8);
 console.log(paws.toString());
```

Comment: this is great! the only thing is i found that only paws.play works. How would i change this if I also wanted to make paws.sleep, paws.pet, and paws.feed work? I've been playing around, but don't really understand why it isn't working

Comment: can you elaborate on what does not work? do you get an error? if you add ` paws.feed(6);` then toString() will print "paws is not hungry."

Comment: hey, yes, so if you changed paws.feed, paws. sleep, paws.pet values the string won't change. so for example if we have paws.feed(8) or paws.feed(1) or paws.feed(12), etc, the string always outputs "paws is hungry" and same goes for paws.sleep.   
const paws = new Cat("paws");
 paws.play(6);
 paws.feed(2);
 paws.sleep(8)
 paws.pet(3)
 console.log(paws.toString());
//paws is not tired. paws is hungry. paws is not lonely. paws is happy.

Comment: I just added ` paws.feed(8);` to my solution and console.log is showing "not hungry"

Comment: you're absolutely right, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

you need to instantiate the Paws class. `let paws = new Paws();`

Answer (score 0):

Many things to say about this code.
First of all, if you put arguments in the constructor you can define the starting properties of the cat, but that is just a detail

```js
    constructor(tiredness=0,hunger=0,loneliness=0,happiness=0) {
        this.tiredness = tiredness;
        this.hunger = hunger;
        this.loneliness = loneliness;
        this.happiness = happiness;
    }
```

and to answer your question, you should instanciate the object.

```js
const paws = new Paws({tiredness : 4});
paws.play(2,4,6)
paws.printStatus();
/*
The cat is not tired
The cat is not hungry
The cat is not lonely
The cat is not happy
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

@KyleDePace already responded this:

```
let paws = new Paws();
console.log(paws.tiredness);
```

As you asked about shorting the code, in the `printStatus()` you can use ternary operators.

```
class Paws {
 constructor() {
  this.tiredness = 0;
  this.hunger = 0;
  this.loneliness = 0;
  this.happiness = 0;
 }

 play(tirednessVal, lonelinessVal, hungerVal) {
  this.tiredness += tirednessVal;
  this.loneliness -= lonelinessVal;
  this.hunger += hungerVal;
 }

 sleep(tirednessVal, lonelinessVal) {
  this.tiredness -= tirednessVal;
  this.loneliness += lonelinessVal;
 }

 eat(hungerVal, happinessVal) {
  this.hunger -= hungerVal;
  this.happiness += happinessVal;
 }

 getAngry(happinessVal) {
  this.happiness -= happinessVal;
 }

 printStatus() {
  console.log(this.tiredness > 10 ? "The cat is very tired" : "The cat is not tired");
  console.log(this.hunger > 10 ? "The cat is very hungry" : "The cat is not hungry");
  console.log(this.loneliness > 10 ? "The cat is very lonely" : "The cat is not lonely");
  console.log(this._happiness > 10 ? "The cat is super happy" : "The cat is not happy");
 }

 pet() {
  if (this.happiness < 5)
   console.log("Meow. Don't touch me!");
  else
    meow();
 }   
 
 meow() {
  console.log("Moew. Pet me more");
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One that you need to create object from your class `Paws` using `new` keyword.

But also in order for your methods to work as per logic, there has to be a values on variables of class which you may also provide during object creation itself.

```
const paw = new Paws(6,7,9,8);
```

```js
class Paws {
     constructor(tiredness,hunger,loneliness,happiness) {
       this.tiredness = tiredness;
       this.hunger = hunger;
       this.loneliness = loneliness;
       this.happiness = happiness;
      }

      play(tirednessVal, lonelinessVal, hungerVal) {
       this.tiredness += tirednessVal;
       this.loneliness -= lonelinessVal;
       this.hunger += hungerVal;
      }
  
      sleep(tirednessVal, lonelinessVal) {
      this.tiredness -= tirednessVal;
      this.loneliness += lonelinessVal;
     }

      eat(hungerVal, happinessVal) {
      this.hunger -= hungerVal;
      this.happiness += happinessVal;
     }

      getAngry(happinessVal) {
       this.happiness -= happinessVal;
     }

     printStatus() {
      const isTired = "The cat is very tired";
      const isNotTired = "The cat is not tired";
      const isHungry = "The cat is very hungry";
      const isNotHungry = "The cat is not hungry";
      const isLonely = "The cat is very lonely";
      const isNotLonely = "The cat is not lonely";
      const isHappy = "The cat is super happy";
      const isNotHappy = "The cat is not happy";

      if (this.tiredness > 10) {
        console.log(isTired);
      } else {
          console.log(isNotTired);
      }
  
      if (this.hunger > 10) {
        console.log(isHungry);
      } else {
       console.log(isNotHungry);
      }
  
      if (this.loneliness > 10) {
        console.log(isLonely);
      } else {
      console.log(isNotLonely);
     }
  
     if (this._happiness > 10) {
       console.log(isHappy);
     } else {
     console.log(isNotHappy);
     }
   }

     pet() {
      if (this.happiness < 5) {
       console.log("Meow. Don't touch me!");
      } else {
       meow();
      }
    }   
    meow() {
  console.log("Moew. Pet me more");
 }
 }
 

const paw = new Paws(6,7,9,8); 

console.log(paw.tiredness);
```